# Convert nested JSON string to list of java object

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I have this json String

```
{"data":"[Level [key=LevelKey [keyEnd=0], Description=abc], Level [key=levelKey [keyEnd=1], Description=xyz]", "id":"123"}
```

And corresponding java classes are

```
public class Level {
  public LevelKey key;
  public String id;
 }


 public class LevelKey{
 public String keyEnd;
 }
```

I want to convert this `data` json string to list of `Level` object using Jackson

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Level> arr = mapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<List<Level>>(){});
```

But I am getting below error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Level': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

Is there any other method to parse it?

Comment: the part of `"[Level [key=LevelKey [keyEnd=0], Description=abc], Level [key=levelKey [keyEnd=1], Description=xyz]"` is not a valid json but a whole string, you will have to parse it yourself i.e write a class that can extract all the values like **key**, **keyEnd** and **Description** to variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below does not look like a proper JSON for the purpose (except for a standard fixed string)

```
"[Level [key=LevelKey [keyEnd=0], Description=abc], Level [key=levelKey [keyEnd=1], Description=xyz]"
```

You could correct the data part of your JSON to something like below (Closest to your JSON in question) :

```
[\"Level [key=LevelKey [keyEnd=0], Description=abc]\",\" Level [key=levelKey [keyEnd=1], Description=xyz]\"]
```

> Is there any other method to parse it?

You could use a direct class reference of `ArrayList` instead of having to instantiate `TypeReference` like below to parse the above (corrected) json string :

```
List<Level> arr = mapper.readValue(data, (new ArrayList<Level>()).getClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting one I must say. Take a look at code snippet I think I got it correct :

```
String data ="{\"data\":\"[Level [key=LevelKey [keyEnd=0], Description=abc], Level [key=levelKey [keyEnd=1], Description=xyz]\", \"id\":\"123\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
List<Level> arr = mapper.readValue(data, (new ArrayList<Level>()).getClass());
System.out.println(arr);
```

I got the following output :

```
[{data=[Level [key=LevelKey [keyEnd=0], Description=abc], Level [key=levelKey [keyEnd=1], Description=xyz], id=123}]
```

Also if you encountered any JsonParseException which according to documentation means :

> Exception type for parsing problems, used when non-well-formed content
>   (content that does not conform to JSON syntax as per specification) is
>   encountered.

So while hacking the JSON you can update the ObjectMapper object like this :

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

Also as mentioned by Exception_al using a direct class reference of ArrayList instead of having to instantiate TypeReference like below to parse the above (corrected) json string.

```
List<Level> arr = mapper.readValue(data, (new ArrayList<Level>()).getClass());
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

The String is not the JSON representation of what you expect you get deserialized into JAVA.
This is a JSON String:

```
"{"data":[{"key":{"keyEnd":0},"Description":"abc"},{"key":{"keyEnd":1},"Description":"abc"}],"id":"123"}"
```

So, there is either a problem with the String or you need to do the parsing yourself.